# ionic app size issue. i have tried with release build but still not work

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I'll create ionic app build with just blank template but still app size is around 8MB so how to decrease app size.i have already tried with release build but still not works for me any idea please tell me about it.

i'll use this command for release build

```
ionic cordova build android --release
```

Comment: Please delete www folder and try again. I think that helps.

Comment: Are you talking about the `apk` , `ipa` size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete platform and www folder and run command =>

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

I think you are build your project in debug mode that's why the size of your app is increasing.